# select text and hint other same text

Tags: sublimetext2

When I select Button, other line "Button"  surrounded by rectangle, like this:

[image: pic1]

When I select Button, other line "Button"  don't have rectangle, like this:

[image: pic2]

word_separators remove ".:"

```
"word_separators": "/\\()\"'-,;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

how to control rectangle

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with plugins. The auto-highlighting functionality only works for selecting whole words, meaning they are surrounded by word boundaries (`\b` in regex-speak). When you remove `.` and `:` from `"word_separators"`, those characters are no longer treated as word boundaries, and `Button` in the line

```
ccui.Button:create(string,string,string,int)
```

is no longer selected. Easy fix: add `.` and `:` back to `"word_separators"`, so you get something like this:

[image]